# Format date in R with lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

My input data, formatted as character, looks like this

```
"2020-07-10T00:00:00"
```

I tried

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hms("2020-07-10T00:00:00", format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', tz=Sys.timezone())
```

But I get

> [1] NA NA
> Warning message:
> All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

I tried the more flexibel approach `parse_date_time()`, but without luck

```
parse_date_time("2020-07-10T00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', tz=Sys.timezone())
```

How can I convert this date "2020-07-10T00:00:00" to a date R recognizes? Note: I am not interested in the time really, only the date!

Comment: Neither `mdy_hms` nor `parse_date_time` have a `format` argument. Are you confusing `lubridate::mdy_hms` with base R's `strptime("2020-07-10T00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that the 07 is the month of July, and the 10 is the 10th:

```
x <- "2020-07-10T00:00:00"
ymd_hms(x, tz = Sys.timezone())

> [1] "2020-07-10 AEST"
```

If it's in format year-day-month, swap the ymd for ydm.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
as.Date("2020-07-10T00:00:00")
# [1] "2020-07-10"
```

Fun fact:

```
as.Date("2020-07-101sddT00:1sdafsdfsdf0:00sdfzsdfsdfsdf")
# [1] "2020-07-10"
```